# Деплой телеграм бота на сервер

Tags: python, telegram-bot, systemd

Как правильно развернуть бота на сервере? Ос сервера Ubuntu. Бот полностью написан на Python. Интересует, что использовать для автоматического включения бота в случае падения серверов телеграмма. Почитал про systemd, supervisor, веб-хуки. Что из этого более правильный выбор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd самое рациональное решение, supervisor считается устаревшим